# Can I store Image from android to Computer through WebService?

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-layout

I am developing Android web app.I need to store image at one common place.so I tried to store image in database.but it doesn't retrieve image.so now I need to save image in my computer and get Image from computer.is it possible?

Comment: send image using multipart entry and create webservice on server side to receive the multipart file.......

Comment: @Shreeshesh: can you send any reference link? please

Comment: @Shreeshesh: i have used List<NameValuePair> to pass value from client to server.is it correct?

Comment: google it for "how to send image on sever using multipart in android "........ U R PHP SCRIPT MUST ME PERFECT